# Adding tasks from script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I'm not able to create tasks from script.
Neither of the below are working.

`var newlist = Tasks.newTaskList().setTitle("This tasklist is created from script");`

`var newTask = Tasks.newTask().setTitle("This task has been created from script");`

I'm new to Google apps script. What am I doing wrong? I've also added the OAuthApp library.
But I'm always getting

> ReferenceError: "Tasks" is not defined.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable the Tasks API? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_tasks

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Although I'm still struggling to figure out where to use the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should create a project with the Tasks API enabled here - https://code.google.com/apis/console/
2. Copy the key, and then in the Script Editor, in the menu go Resources -> Use Google APIs and paste in the key

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did paste the key where indicated; but I'm still not able to create a new list, nor  new task. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to send the key as parameter somewhere?

Comment: Are you getting the same error message you mention above? Can you confirm that you only pasted the key where in the screen shot above says "YOUR_KEY_HERE" and no where else?

Comment: No, that error was fixed when the API was turned on. But the new task or new list does not appear in my tasks.

Comment: Do I have to add any code for saving it?
Documents, Spreadsheets, Contacts & Events also don't need any extra code for saving after being created, so I assumed Tasks wouldn't either. But do I?

Comment: Infact 
`newlist.getTitle();`
is returning the title
but
`newlist.getSelfLink();`
is returning null

Is there a problem somewhere? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Its working. I missed this line
`Tasks.Tasklists.insert(newList);`
Sorry for the mess on this thread. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok glad to know. Please close out this question with that comment when you get a chance.