# How to add tasks in Google Task using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-tasks-api

I need to insert tasks in google tasks using a google sheets.

I need help to know what to do, how to start.

I found some paid programs to integrate this, but I want to do it myself.

If somebody could help me, I appreciate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14588750/7215091

Comment: If you can search SO then this search will return 208 links `[google-apps-script] tasks API`